# update several columns from a complex select with distinct

Tags: mysql, select

I have a complex select query from table1 that returns 2 columns of data (id and value)

I want to update columns id and value of table2 with that data.

How can i do it ?

I have tried something like this

update table2 set (id, value) values (select ....)

and other things, but no results :P

NOTE & EDIT: I've seen about UPDATE INNER JOIN but the problem is that my select is complex ... it's like

```
select distinct(colA), sum(case statement....) as c1, sum(case statement...) as c2 from table2 group by colA
```

and colA, c1 and c2 is what i want to update in other table

thank you

Comment: I don't understand one thing. If you have to set id on table2 how do you identify matching between tables? Sorry for my english but I hope you've understood my doubt.